# correct incrementing of primary key in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, auto-increment

I use sqlite3 and have a simple table

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `item_id` INTEGER,
  `item`    TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY(item_id)
);
```

Inserting some values:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO `data` (`item`) VALUES ('A'), ('A'), ('B');
```

This will result in:

```
`item_id` | `item`
----------+-------
    1     |   A   
    3     |   B
```

Is it possible to get the incrementing of the primary key in a correct way like:

```
`item_id` | `item`
----------+-------
    1     |   A   
    2     |   B
```

Comment: There's no guarantee of continuity on primary keys. This is common in most databases, because not only can rows be deleted, but a transaction may be rolled back -- all the primary keys generated during the transaction are lost (and another transaction may be running in parallel on another thread so the next ID can't just be rolled back too). As usual, the [SQLite documentation on autoincrement is excellent](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

Comment: Tried to reproduce, but my version of SQLite (3.11.0) throws a "UNIQUE constraint failed" error on that insert statement. How are you avoiding that?

Comment: Ups.... Use `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ....`

Comment: If you care about the values of your primary keys, and not just that it *has* a unique value, don't use autoincrement primary keys. Simple as that.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding the AUTOINCREMENT keyword to the 'item_id' column, and then specifying by how much the value increments:

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `item_id` INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT (1, 1),
  `item`    TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY(item_id)
);
```

I'm not entirely sure if it will work, but I am working with MS-SQL at the moment, and the syntax for creating a table seems fairly similar.

Hope this helps.

Comment: SQLite doesn't allow parameters passed after AUTOINCREMENT, and it can only be part of a PRIMARY KEY clause. ([source](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html))

Comment: Ah, well that sucks. The simplest things you want to do is always the hardest. Thanks for the clarification though.